# Better alternative to lots of IF statements? Table of values

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, dictionary

I have a table of moves that decide whether or not the player wins based on their selection against the AI. Think Rock, Paper, Scissors with a lot more moves.
I'll be eventually coding it in Python, but before I begin, I want to know if there is a better way of doing this rather than LOTS and LOTS of IF statements?

The table looks like this:

[image]

I'm thinking that the moves will need to be assigned numbers, or something like that? I don't know where to start...

Comment: Maybe create a class called move and give the a list of moves that beat the original and ones that lose to the original. Identify the move by a name and if the name of the opposing move is in one of the predefined list you use that outcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a dict? Something like this:

```
#dict of winning outcomes, the first layer represents the AI moves, and the inner 
#layer represent the player move and the outcome
ai = {
    'punch' : {
        'punch' : 'tie',
        'kick' : 'wins',
    },
    'stab' : {
        'punch' : 'loses',
        'kick' : 'loses'
    }
}

ai_move = 'punch'
player_move = 'kick'
print ai[ai_move][player_move] #output: wins


ai_move = 'stab'
player_move = 'punch'
print ai[ai_move][player_move] #output: loses
```

I didn't map out all the moves, but you get the gist

Comment: haha ye luckily I had my editor open and ready on my other screen @burakozgul

Comment: @dhdavvie yours seems the most logical so far

Comment: @Jason obviously I'm biased but I agree. writing out the entire table will be a bit annoying, but once its done you can reference is anywhere and its super easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a map of attacks similar to your table above like this

```
map = [
    [0,-1,-1,1,1,-1],
    [1,0,-1,-1,1,-1],
    [1,1,0,-1,-1,1],
    [-1,1,1,0,-1,1],
    [-1,-1,1,1,0,-1],
    [1,1,-1,-1,1,0]
]
```

Here, 0 is a draw, 1 is a win and -1 is a loss.

Now create an array of attacks where the places of the attacks corresponds with the map above.

```
attacks = ["Punch", "Kick", "Stab", "Throw", "Fling", "Uppercut"]
```

Now you can easily find out if one attack beats another

```
map[attacks.index("Stab")][attacks.index("Punch")]

>>> 1
```

Stab wins over punch

Comment: Note: This is my first time ever writing python. If something seems off, please comment or just edit my post.

Comment: imo a nested dictionary with textual keys/values is much more readable than a 2d array with mapped values

Comment: @CraigBurgler While you do have a point that the map is less readable than a dictionary, I think the compactness, plus the programmatic advantage that you can retrieve an integer value instead of a string outweighs the cons. Adding new attacks is also faster in this format.

Comment: The only value of compactness is as an attribute of readability, and clarity is far more important. The nested dictionary is actually slightly more compact when it is used to get outcomes; the 2d array with mapped values is only more compact on initial data population.

Comment: Also there is no "programmatic advantage" to retrieving an integer value over a string from what we know of the OP's use case. If there was we could easily change our dictionary values to numeric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121061/discussion-between-craig-burgler-and-jurgemaister).

Comment: I think both approaches are fine. It's a matter of style. I prefer the array because it's less verbose and a little bit easier to write or generate from the original table.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a 2-dimensional list for this. Each attack is decoded to an index 0 to 5 and win tie and loss are decoded as 1, 0 and -1.

So the list will look something like this (not based on your example, I just put some random numbers):

```
table = [[1,0,-1,0,1,-1],[1,1,0,1,0,-1],...,etc.]
```

And you will retrieve it like this:

```
table[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, store the decisions as key/value pairs in a dictionary with all the possible combinations as the key and decision as result. Basically make a lookup table for the possible moves.

This speeds up decision making at the expense of having to store all possible combinations.

```
def tie():
    print("It's a tie!")

def lose():
    print("You lose")

def win():
    print("You win")
moves = { 
     # player_ai action
    'punch_punch': tie,
    'punch_kick': lose,
    'punch_stab': lose,
    <..>
}
player_move = <move>
ai_move = <move>
key = "_".join([player_move, ai_move])
if key in moves:
    # Execute appropriate function
    return moves[key]()
raise Exception("Invalid move")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dictionary of dictionaries (nested dictionary). Keep values and keys in text form, rather than map to numbers, to improve readability.

```
outcome = {}
outcome['punch'] = {}
outcome['punch']['punch'] = 'Tie'
outcome['punch']['kick'] = 'Lose'
...
outcome['kick'] = {}
outcome['kick']['punch'] = 'Win'
outcome['kick']['kick'] = 'Tie'
...
i_do = 'punch'
he_does = 'fling'
...
if outcome[i_do][he_does] == 'Win':
    print("Woohoo!")
```

Comment: As a comment to readability: The verbosity of this approach makes the code very hard to maintain. Write out all the attacks, and perhaps add a few  more and you'll quickly realise that this is not easy to read at all.

Comment: The "verbosity" aids in maintenance, and is actually only more verbose on initial population of data which can be performed in a helper function. When I get into the logic of my code I would much rather work with statements of the form `if outcome[i_do][he_does] == 'Win':` than `if map[attacks.index("i_do")][attacks.index("he_does")] == 1:`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a python dictionary to map moves to numbers:

```
move = {'Punch': 0, 'Kick': 1}
```

And then use a matrix to determine the outcome. Numpy can be used for that

```
import numpy
move = {'Punch': 0, 'Kick': 1}

outcome = numpy.matrix([['Tie','Loses'],['Wins','Tie']])


# Punch vs Punch => Tie
print outcome[move['Punch'], move['Punch']]

# Punch vs Kick => Punch loses
print outcome[move['Punch'], move['Kick']]
```